# Append image to image.source in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I am trying to append image to image source but after executing the code image is not displaying in my page.

Code:

```
 Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)data.img;
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
 ms.Position = 0;
 BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
 bi.BeginInit();
 bi.StreamSource = ms;
 bi.EndInit();
 imgPhoto.Source = bi;
```

this is data.img specifications that I want to append to imhPhoto.Source.

[image: this is data.img specifications]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working around this issue, the solution for this question is:

call the function to get BitmapImage and save it in photo variable like this:

```
BitmapImage photo = byteToImage(byte[] buffer)
```

this functionto convert byte to BitmapImage

```
public BitmapImage byteToImage(byte[] buffer)
{

 using(var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
 {
   var image = new BitmapImage();
   image.BeginInit();
   image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
   image.StreamSource =  ms;
   image.EndInit();
 }

 return image;
}
```

finally, append converted  photo to image source like this:

```
imgPhoto.Source = photo;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can assign path like this.

```
  //for App folder path
            //var path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)+"\\Image\\pic.jpg";

            //for machine path
            var path = @"C:\Users\User1\Pictures\pic.jpg";

            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(path);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            ms.Position = 0;
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.StreamSource = ms;
            bi.EndInit();
            imgPhoto.Source = bi;
```

Answer (score -2):

If this solves your problem :

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(@"g:\screenshot.png");

BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
ms.Position = 0;            

bi.StreamSource = ms;
bi.EndInit();

imgPhoto.Source = bi;
```

Comment: it says `imgPhoto.Source.Metadata threw an exception of type System.NotSupportedException ` and image not display yet..

Comment: can you look at RawFormat in attached picture? I think that is the main issue, but I dont know how to make it know format